# grails create query: wrong pagination with totalCount

Tags: grails, pagination, hibernate-criteria

I'm using a criteria query with pagination.  The query works fine, but the totalCount is bigger than the count expected. Is there any duplication issue?

```
def idList =  CS.createCriteria().list (params) {
      projections { distinct ( "id" ) 
          property("date")
          property("id")
      }
      cpNames{
           eq("login",login)    
}
      order("date","desc")
}

   return idList
```

In gsp side, the pagination (idList.totalCount) is wrong: bigger than my list.

Answer (score 1):

> The listDistinct() method does not work well with the pagination options maxResult and firstResult. If you need distinct results with pagination, we currently recommend that you use HQL. You can find out more information from this blog post.

[http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html)